# Change Windows 7 Serial Number

Tags: c#, windows-7

I want to make a little Licene Management with C#.

With a common PC-Image, i set up some workstations without a serial number and then I want to change the serial number with a c# daemon.

My question:
how can I change the serial number and activate windows 7 using C#?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [slmgr.vbs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793433.aspx).
You can call it using `Process.Start`.